# Why is spinner drop down item transparent?

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I created my custom spinner extends from androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner, however the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`
drop down items are transparent.

I have the exact same code in other project using the same `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` but that drop down has a white background by default. I want to know where does `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` looks for the background?
Is there any default style it is using?

Page is Gray background, and the drop down item using the same gray background.

[image].

Relevant code

Nothing special in my theme or style folder

```kotlin
    inner class DropDownAdapter: BaseAdapter(){

        private var spinnerOptions: List<String> = ArrayList()

        fun updateOptions(options: List<String>?){
            ...
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return spinnerOptions.size
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return spinnerOptions[position]
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return 0
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            //provide the item selected view

            var view = convertView
            if (view == null){
                view = TextView(context)
                view.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
            }
            val textView = view as TextView
            textView.text = spinnerOptions[position]
            textView.setPadding(20,80,20,80)
            view.textSize = 16f
            view.maxLines = 1
            return textView
        }

        override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            //provide the drop down view for each item

            var view = convertView
            if (convertView == null){
                val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
                view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false)
                view.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
                //view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE). I know I could set the background here, but I want to know why it is not enabled by DEFAULT
            }
            val textView = view as TextView
            textView.text = spinnerOptions[position]
            textView.setPadding(20,80,20,60)
            view.textSize = 16f
            view.maxLines = 1
            return textView
        }
    }
```

This view is dynamically created, I am not interested in hard coding any xml. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add this to xml  android:popupBackground="@android:color/white"